# Translation of a phrase about unknown people into Latin

Tags: idiom, sentence-translation

What would be the way to say that you don't care about people you don't know? Something like "I don't care about those I don't know" or "I ignore the faceless masses."

Answer (score 4):

Cicero has a fun, "pile-on" quote in *Pro Fonteio* 32:

> potestis igitur ignotos notis, iniquos aequis, alienigenas domesticis, cupidos moderatis, mercennarios    gratuitis, impios religiosis, inimicissimos huic imperio ac nomini bonis ac fidelibus et sociis et civibus anteferre?

Using him as a model, you could say:

> **notos ignotis antefero.**

Literally:

> I prefer people I know to people I don't know.

It puts a slightly more positive spin on your phrase than you may want, but it has a nice ring to it!

Answer (score 3):

There are many words for "unknown", but many of them have tones you might want to avoid.
For example, *ignobilis* implies low birth and *alienus* implies being foreign or perhaps unwelcome, although both could be used for *unknown*.
The most neutral word I could think of is *ignotus*.
The masculine plural is a good choice for unknown people in general.

The verb [*contemnere*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=contemno&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059) can be translated as "to consider a person or thing as unimportant or of small value", and I think that's a pretty good fit.

Combining these, I would suggest this phrase:

> *Ignotos contemno.*
>   I consider unknown [people] to be unimportant.

The English translation is a bit clumsy, but attempts to give a good idea of the meaning.
A more fluent translation might be "I ignore the unknown", but I shall not endeavor a better English phrase here since the question was about Latin.

Answer (score 3):

Catullus XCII is the contemptuous and snappy put-down of Julius Caesar, *nil nimium studeo, Caesar, tibi velle placere, nec scire utrum sis albus an ater homo*, or 'I've not the least wish to please you, Caesar, or even to know whether you are a white man or black'. Leaving out the personal stuff, you might reduce this to

*Ignotis nil nimium studeo*,

— or 'I don't pay too much attention to those I don't know'.

Comment: Are you sure you can use *studeo* + acc. for a person?

Comment: @brianpck In a word, yes. The dative in the Catullus is governed by _placere_. Smith gives several examples.

Comment: I don't have Smith available: could you give an example? L&S says that *studeo* + acc is "mostly with neuter pronouns and adjectives" and that it "very rarely" has a noun definite object, citing two examples that use *res*. All the examples with persons are genitive ("studeo tui") or dative ("studeo tibi").

Comment: @brianpck As it happens, none of Smith's examples is a noun, except for _res_, but unlike the much later L&S (which allows that an acc. is rare) he made no comment on this. Well, thank you: we learn something every day, and I'll change the answer.